# Figure made by two different size images, automatically scaled, with single caption

Tags: floats, floatrow

In order to get a figure made by two different size images **automatically scaled to the same height and to full text width**, with a single caption, I tried to adapt some examples from [floatrow](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/floatrow/floatrow.pdf) package.
Unfortunately, as shown by the following MWE, the results were unsatisfactory. In one case the caption is missing, in the other there is no separation between the two images.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\CommonHeightRow{\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics[height=\CommonHeight]{example-image-16x10}}{}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics[height=\CommonHeight]{example-image-10x16}}{}
\end{floatrow}}
\caption{This is a caption.}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}[htb]
\CommonHeightRow{\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics[height=\CommonHeight]{example-image-16x10}}{\includegraphics[height=\CommonHeight]{example-image-10x16}}
\end{floatrow}}
\caption{This is a caption.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

I know that there are many ways to obtain the desired result, but I found none, apart from [floatrow](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/floatrow/floatrow.pdf), able to **automatically scale** two different size images to same height and full text width.

Thanks in advance for any help.

## Follow up

To summarize, a great solution to obtain **automatically scaled double image figures** that addittionally let you **choose the total width** (90% of text width in the following snippet) can be

```
\newlength\mylength
\begin{adjustbox}{width=0.9\textwidth,center=\textwidth,caption={This is a caption.},label={some:label},figure=htb}
\adjustimage{gstore height=\mylength}{example-image-16x10}%
\hspace{1em}%
\adjustimage{height=\mylength}{example-image-10x16}%
\end{adjustbox}%
```

which has the only drawback that separation between images changes slightly depending on images aspect ratio (other solutions addressing such drawback are welcome!). If you absolutely want a fixed separation you can stick with a more traditional solution in which you have to **manually set the height, usually by iterative tentatives**:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-16x10}%
\hspace{1em}%
\includegraphics[height=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-10x16}%
\caption{This is a caption.}%
\label{some:label}%
\end{figure}
```

[Here is a MWE](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/odgvRV).

Comment: Please use `example-image-a` and `example-image-b` (and others) for code examples. These are provided by the `mwe` package on CTAN. This way others can easily compile your code examples without the need for the `demo` option.

Comment: If you need different image sizes just use `example-image-16x10` and `example-image-10x16`. See `mwe` package for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `adjustbox` package for this. Just use `gstore height` to store the original height of the first image, scale the second image height to it and then scale the whole thing to the wanted width. Use a `\hspace` to get some distance between the images (which will be scaled however!).

You can even get rid of the `figure` environment by using the `figure` key of the outer `adjustbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength\mylength

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\linewidth}
\adjustimage{gstore height=\mylength}{example-image-16x10}%
\hspace{1em}%
\adjustimage{height=\mylength}{example-image-10x16}%
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{This is a caption.}
\end{figure}

\lipsum


\begin{adjustbox}{width=\linewidth,rotate=0,caption={This is a caption},figure=htb}
\adjustimage{gstore height=\mylength}{example-image-16x10}%
\hspace{1em}%
\adjustimage{height=\mylength}{example-image-10x16}%
\end{adjustbox}
% Note the `rotate=0` key is required for `adjustbox` v1.0 to enforce the resizing to happen before the `figure` environment is applied, not after. Starting with v1.1 this is done automatically.

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also, you can use the `margin` key to add some white space to the right of the first image. This way you don't need to use `\hspace`.

Comment: The solution works perfectly for full width, but if I set a fixed `margin` (say `4em`) I get different figure widths across the document, probably due to variable aspect ratio of images. The best solution would be to use a reduced width for adjustbox environment (say `0.8\linewidth`) and center the figure, but I could not make `center` option work.

Comment: @mmj: Try `\textwidth` instead of `\linewidth`, it should be more constant. The `center` option needs to be placed after `width` (but before any `figure` key). Best use explictly `center=\textwidth`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe using `adjustbox` would be a workarund?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}
    \includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-16x10}
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{caption}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Drawback: if your images do not contain white space, you have to manually insert space between the images, e.g. by using `\quad` or `\hspace{...}`. This space will also be scales, so may be different for different images.

Comment: Interesting solution for two images figures, but it's not what I'm looking for, because you have to provide the height.

Comment: @mmj: Well, the height is scaled anyway due to the `width` scaling. As all scaling does not change the quality this is not a problem. The only problem might be if you need to scale a very small image to a very large one, so that the scaling factor is to large. However, in that case providing a fixed height for the first scaling is actually better!

Comment: @mmj You don't really have to provide the height, you just have to provide the same length for both images, the value does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I also found a solution using the `floatrow` package, here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{figure*}[htbp]
\ffigbox[1.0\linewidth]{}{\CommonHeightRow{\begin{subfloatrow}[2]% this comment needed, otherwise an unprotected space shifts slightly the figure to the right
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics[height=\CommonHeight]{example-image-10x16}}{\label{fig:01a}}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics[height=\CommonHeight]{example-image-16x10}}{\label{fig:01b}}
\end{subfloatrow}}
\caption{A figure caption.}\label{fig:01a+01b}}
\end{figure*}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

The total width can be set by changing `1.0\linewidth` to any fraction you wish.

This solution is interesting because with the same `floatrow` package you are able to automatically scale many combinations of multiple images/figures with or without subcaptions, like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/433408/28685) and [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/432996/28685).