# Automatic scaling of side by side figures

Tags: floatrow, sidebyside

I'm using a quite satisfying solution for side by side independent caption figures, a solution by which images are sized automatically to same height and to text width, see MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{figure*}
\CommonHeightRow{\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics[height=\CommonHeight]{example-image-16x10}}{\caption{A caption.}\label{fig:01}}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics[height=\CommonHeight]{example-image-10x16}}{\caption{Another caption.}\label{fig:02}}
\end{floatrow}}
\end{figure*}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

However sometimes I would like to limit the overall width of the two figures to something less (say 80%) than text width (retaining the uniform height), but I couldn't find a way to achieve it. (For some reason the naive solution of adding a scalar prefix to `\CommonHeight`, such as `0.8\CommonHeight`, gives an error.)

Thanks in advance for any clue.

Solutions using a package other than `floatrow` are welcomed, as long as they automatically size images height and overall width by a given percentage of text width, as required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `floatrow` package has two macros, `\FRleftmargin` and `\FRrightmargin` which are, by default, `\hfill`. You can redefine each of them to be `\hspace{0.1\textwidth}` so the space left for the figures will be `0.8\textwidth`.

> [image]

(rule for scale :)

The definition must be *before* `\begin{floatrow}`. If you put it inside `\begin{figure}` it will be valid for the current figure only, otherwise it will take effect until you redefine it.

I made a little command that will take as argument the desired width of the figures. The command will then balance it and pass to `\FRleftmargin` and `\FRrightmargin`. Just call `\ThisWidth{0.8\textwidth}` after `\begin{figure}` (or `\begin{figure*}`, of course :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\makeatletter
\def\ThisWidth#1{%
  \@tempdima\dimexpr(\textwidth-#1)/2\relax
  \edef\FRleftmargin{\noexpand\hspace*{\the\@tempdima}}%
  \edef\FRrightmargin{\noexpand\hspace*{\the\@tempdima}}%
  \ignorespaces}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\blindtext

\begin{figure*}
\ThisWidth{0.8\textwidth}
\CommonHeightRow{\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics[height=\CommonHeight]{example-image-16x10}}{\caption{A caption.}\label{fig:01}}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics[height=\CommonHeight]{example-image-10x16}}{\caption{Another caption.}\label{fig:02}}
\end{floatrow}}
\rule{0.8\textwidth}{2pt}
\end{figure*}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great job, thanks! Maybe you are able to make your solution work (I couldn't) also on this other figure with side by side automatically scaled images with subcaptions (needs `subcaption` package); `\begin{figure*}
\ffigbox{}{\CommonHeightRow{\begin{subfloatrow}[2]
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics[height=\CommonHeight]{example-image-10x16}}{\caption{A subcaption.}\label{fig:01a}}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics[height=\CommonHeight]{example-image-16x10}}{\caption{Another subcaption.}\label{fig:01b}}
\end{subfloatrow}}
\caption{The figure caption.}\label{fig:01a+01b}}
\end{figure*}`

Comment: If you think it's better to start another question I'll be glad to do it, otherwise (if your solution fits both cases) I will update this question.

Comment: @mmj I looked at your example code... My solution will not work for `subfloatrow` because it makes `\FRleftmargin` and `\FRrightmargin` empty and uses another scheme to place the figures, so simply redefining the environment doesn't work :/ I think your best bet is to ask a new question, so more people will see it. Add a link to this question to give a start :)

Comment: I started a new question about the similar problem: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/433408/28685