# Automatic scaling of figure with side by side images with subcaption

Tags: floatrow, sidebyside

I'm using a quite satisfying solution for figures with side by side images with subcaption, a solution by which images are sized automatically to same height and to text width, see MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{figure*}[htb]
\ffigbox{}{\CommonHeightRow{\begin{subfloatrow}[2]% this comment needed, see 1st comment to question
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics[height=\CommonHeight]{example-image-10x16}}{\caption{A subcaption.}\label{fig:01a}}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics[height=\CommonHeight]{example-image-16x10}}{\caption{Another subcaption.}\label{fig:01b}}
\end{subfloatrow}}
\caption{The composite figure caption.}\label{fig:01a+01b}}
\end{figure*}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

However sometimes I would like to limit the overall width of the two figures to something less (say 80%) than text width (retaining the uniform height), but I couldn't find a way to achieve it. A [very nice solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/433238/28685) to [a similar problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/432996/28685) does not seem to work in this case.

Thanks in advance for any clue.

Solutions using a package other than `floatrow` are welcomed, as long as they automatically size images height and overall width by a given percentage of text width, as required.

P.S. I just noticed a slight shift of figure to the right, maybe some `floatrow` package expert can help to fix this too.

Comment: The shift to the right is due to an unprotected space at the end of the line. Where you have `\begin{subfloatrow}[2]` add a comment character at the end of the line: `\begin{subfloatrow}[2]%` and the space will be gone. [See this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/407620/134574) for an explanation on spaces at the end of the lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

width of `ffigbox` you can determine with option width:

```
\ffigbox[<width>][<height<][<vert pos<]{<caption>}{<object>}
```

in your case try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{figure*}[htb]
\ffigbox[0.8\linewidth]{}{\CommonHeightRow{\begin{subfloatrow}[2]%
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics[height=\CommonHeight]{example-image-10x16}}{\caption{A subcaption.}\label{fig:01a}}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics[height=\CommonHeight]{example-image-16x10}}{\caption{Another subcaption.}\label{fig:01b}}
\end{subfloatrow}}
\caption{The composite figure caption.}\label{fig:01a+01b}}
\end{figure*}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

is this what you looking for?